# How to make all buttons inline same size bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a navbar with buttons inline, but need to make all the same size and inline.

I'm using bootstrap 4

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

    <div class="bd-exemple">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger shadow"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><br>Protocolo</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary shadow"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i><br>Chat</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><br>Dashboard</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i><br>Agenda</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-injured"></i><br>Pacientes</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-md"></i><br>Equipe Multidiciplinar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-hospital"></i><br>Planos de Saúde</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-capsules"></i><br>Medicamentos</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><br>teste@innovecare.com.br</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow botfr"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>

    </div>
</nav>
```

I need all the buttons to be inline and inside the navbar, except the first and last ones that are smaller and need only have the space of the icon inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set a fixed width to all the buttons in the navbar using css
(excluding the first and last elements)

note that this doesn't solve the issue of text overflow, and if the string is longer than the button width it'll either be cut or overflow.

```css
.bd-exemple .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

    <div class="bd-exemple">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger shadow"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><br>Protocolo</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary shadow"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i><br>Chat</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><br>Dashboard</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i><br>Agenda</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-injured"></i><br>Pacientes</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-md"></i><br>Equipe Multidiciplinar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-hospital"></i><br>Planos de Saúde</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-capsules"></i><br>Medicamentos</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><br>teste@innovecare.com.br</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow botfr"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by wrapping your buttons inside a div and using a `grid` inside a `grid`.

```
.bd-exemple {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

.bd-exemple .equal-widths{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
   word-break: break-all; /*remove if not needed*/
   overflow: hidden; /*remove if not needed*/
}
```

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6vzh8ywn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### Bro Use This!

```css
/*---For inline and width Styling---*/
button {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 2px;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/*---For-BAckground Color & Other styling ---*/
button {
    border: navajowhite;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: buttontext;
    background-color: #f8f9fd;
}


.bd-exemple button:nth-child(2) {
background: #e64a3b;
color: #fff;
}
.bd-exemple button:nth-child(3) {
background: #4c71e0;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

    <div class="bd-exemple">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger shadow"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><br>Protocolo</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary shadow"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i><br>Chat</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><br>Dashboard</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i><br>Agenda</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-injured"></i><br>Pacientes</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-md"></i><br>Equipe Multidiciplinar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-hospital"></i><br>Planos de Saúde</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-capsules"></i><br>Medicamentos</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><br>teste@innovecare.com.br</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light shadow botfr"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>

    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```